# pandas - highlight duplicates data row

Tags: pandas, dataframe

To improve my question

How to check if there are same Cntr_No and same Total_Amount

'HLBU 1234567'and 100 is duplicate.

data:

```
 df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Cntr_No': ['HLBU 1234567','HLBU 1234567'], 'Total_Amount': [100,100]})
 df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Cntr_No': ['HLBU 1234567','HLBU 1234567'], 'Total_Amount': [100,100]})
```

output:

```
  Cntr_No         Total_Amount     Duplicate
0  HLBU 1234567           100         Yes
1  HLBU 1234567           100         Yes
```

Comment: not really what i want to achieve if there are thousands of records

Comment: i trying to have a column to indicate if it is duplicate "Yes" or "No"

Comment: Did you get the answer for this? Did you try something like `df1['Duplicate'] = df1.duplicated(keep=False).map({True:'Yes', False:'No'})`

Comment: @prabhakar thanks it work too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pd.DataFrame.duplicated` to get the duplicated rows as a series. The keyword `keep = False` will mark all the duplicates as True. The map will then rename the True/False values to Yes/No.

```
df1['Duplicate'] = df1.duplicated(keep=False).map({True:'Yes', False:'No'})
```